# how to get form element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I will try work in javascript, I'm not getting form element data

```
function sendInfo(params) {
    var p = event.target;
    Message("Welcome " + p.fname.value + " " + p.lname.value);
}
function Message(m) {
    document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = m;
}
```

I am getting an error message when I will run the script

any suggestion.

Comment: refer dom elements

Comment: How's your `form` tag configured?

Comment: if you can share all necessary codes, that would be helpful.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: what error message? error at which line? Need more details...

Comment: i hope you will get id's value print of form elements

Comment: yes I want output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look :

```
function sendInfo(params) {
    var p = event.target.parentElement;
    Message("Welcome " + p.fname.value + " " + p.lname.value);
}

function Message(m) {
    document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = m;
}
```

try this if possible

Comment: how u can be so sure to use `parentElement` without looking at HTML structure?